# How can you make a stopwatch with the chronometer that shows milliseconds?

Tags: java, android, stopwatch, milliseconds, chronometer

Hi I'm trying to make a scoreboard but I can't figure out how to get it to display milliseconds. In my xml a textview that displays ".000" and in my main java class I have

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   timeEx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeEx);
ending= 000;

View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (running == true){


    }else{

    MyChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeWhenStopped);
    MyChronometer.start();
    running = true;
     TimeEnd();

   }

    }
}

private void TimeEnd() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(running == true){

        ending ++;
        timeEx.setText("."+ ending );
        if (ending == 999)
            ending = ending - 999;

    }
}
```

};
        }

Comment: Please post a short, indented, complete, runnable program that highlights your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elapsedRealtime()` already is in milliseconds (specifically, "[milliseconds since the system was booted, including deep sleep](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html)").

If you want to display the elapsed time as seconds with a decimal point (e.g., the `TextView` should show "2.198"), divide the calculated time difference by 1000. If you only want the milliseconds portion (e.g., the `TextView` should show "198"), then use the modulo operator to get the remainder of division by 1000.